# docker-compose via prisma js

Tags: docker-compose, environment-variables, prisma

I have a full-stack app and folder structure like this:

```bash
.
├── .env
├── client
├── docker-compose.yml
└── server
    └── prisma
        └── schema.prisma
```

In `server/prisma/schema.prisma` I use a common way to pass `DATABASE_URL`:

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

In `./docker-compose.yml` I try to set environment variables using  `env_file` param:

```yaml
services:
  server:
    build: server/
    ports:
      - ${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}
    command: node ./dist/main.js
    env_file:
      - .env
```

And my `.env` file for example:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://admin:<password>@<some_ip>:5432
JWT_SECRET=secret
CLIENT_PORT=3000
SERVER_PORT=3001
```

When I try to run my application:

```
docker-compose up
```

I get this error:

> Error: Prisma schema validation - (get-config wasm)
> Error code: P1012
> error: Environment variable not found: DATABASE_URL.
> -->  schema.prisma:10
> |
> |   provider = "postgresql"
> |   url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
> |

But when I replace my connection url in `server/prisma/schema.prisma` with a const string like this

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = "postgresql://admin:<password>@<some_ip>:5432"
}
```

The app starts normally (expected), I open docker terminal and try to show my `$DATABASE_URL` value, and what I see is this:

```
$ docker exec -it e15c97983f12 sh
$ echo $DATABASE_URL // here i see my DATABASE_URL from my .env file!
```

So, here is a question. How should I pass connection url to my schema file? I know, I could place `.env` file in the `server` folder, but I want to use a common docker-compose way to manage all my env variables in one place.

I have already tried pass environment variables with another docker-compose param *environment*, but it works just like example above

Comment: Have you got the fix for this issue?